# When loading a table to bigquery, google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError is raised everytime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I was loading a json lines file to bigquery. However, it failed because of this error :

```
  File "/home/togayyazar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 102, in refresh
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb\'<!DOCTYPE html>\\n<html lang=en>\\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\\n  <style>\\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\\n  </style>\\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\\n  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That\\xe2\\x80\\x99s an error.</ins>\\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That\\xe2\\x80\\x99s all we know.</ins
```

I've changed credential json file with a new one but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your credentials. It could be related to the authentication method you are using (service-account, user credentials), and how you are using it (from a BigQuery client library, command line tool).

It seems to me that you are using the bq command line tool (part of the google-cloud-sdk) from a Google Compute Engine VM. By default, you have access to a service-account within the instance, if you want to authenticate with another method, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#choosing_an_authorization_type) are the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a typo in your filename/path.

[HTTP Error 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is a NotFound error, meaning it couldn't find something.

Judging by the error in the html it couldn't find `"/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true"`  at the location where you are executing your command, rather than the credentials not having permissions.